# Peoplesoft WebService API/Repository

Tags: xml, web-services, oracle, soa, peoplesoft

Trying to find the XML message and service structure for PeopleSoft web services, similar to SAP's [ESWorkplace](http://esworkplace.sap.com/socoview%28bD1lbiZjPTAwMSZkPW1pbg==%29/render.asp?sap-unique=042646&sap-params=aWQ9RjZDRkMwRUEzRUYxNEJDOTg0MUM1MjgyNzJFRTg1ODMmcGFja2FnZWlkPURFMDQyNkREOUIwMjQ5RjE5NTE1MDAxQTY0RDNGNDYyJm1vZGU9). This [blog posting](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/ofm-psft-blog-postings-094500.html) would seem to indicate that is called the Integrated Service Repository (ISR), however the [link provided](http://www.peoplesoft.com/psp/portprd/CUSTOMER/ISR/c/PTIS_INTEGRATION.PTIS_QUERY_INTG.GBL) doesn't work. Any search queries on the oracle website and forums is bringing back nothing.

So do Oracle still publicly publish PeopleSoft integration points? If so, where? If not, how else does one access the information?

To give some context, I'm part of a SOA integration team and dont have access to any of the PeopleSoft implementation's resources.

**EDIT:** After further search this may be a duplication of [Standard web services API available in PeopleSoft?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315697/standard-web-services-api-available-in-peoplesoft), hopefully in the 2+ years though things have changed!?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the PeopleSoft Web services in the following Navigation.
**Navigation: Main Menu > PeopleTools > Integration Broker > Integration Setup > Services.**
By default, it will list the SOAP Web Services and if you are looking for the REST API you can enable the REST Service Check box.

**Message Structure:**
Search for your web service and drill down where you can find the Existing operations Grid at the bottom where we have the **Operation Tab** - Holds the list of Service Operations inked to this Service and **Message link Tab** - Holds the respective Messages for those Service Operations.

**PayLoad:**
If you would like to see the Payload for the Transaction then follow the below **Navigation - Main Menu > PeopleTools > Integration Broker > Service Operations Monitor > Monitoring > Synchronous Services (or Asynchronous Services).**
Search with your Service Operation Name and click on the link appear in the listed transactions.
It Will Open a new tab of Synchronous Details Page.
In the Log Type you can choose among Request - Original, Request - Transformed, Response - Original, Response - Transformed and view the Payload for the transaction.
You can also find the Error Messages if any.

Regards,
Vivekanandhan [PeopleSoft Web Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpIfr.jpg)